# how to use CSS variable in nightwatch test case

Tags: css, nightwatch.js

I am using CSS variable for one of my component (@value) which I am getting from global CSS constants file (style.css). and I wanted to import this file into nightwatch test to verify the style. I am even not sure if this is really possible since nightwatch not letting me import the @value from CSS. 
Here is the sample code -

Global CSS constant File -

global-style.css

```
@value TopHeaderHeight : 80px;
```

In nightwatch -

```
const styles = require(<path to global-styles>)
```

and used the styles.TopHeaderHeight in nightwatch test but while running I am getting this error at @value -

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Any solution for this ?